# Importing modules from a dependency package's Test-Suite

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'd like to write some tests for my package which depends on a package `foo`, and I'd like to import some code written for `foo`'s `test-suite`, but which isn't exported or exposed in `foo.cabal`.

In other words my dependency `foo.cabal` has this section

```
Test-Suite tests
  Type:               exitcode-stdio-1.0
  Build-Depends:      base, text, parsec >= 3, etc
  Main-Is:            Test/TestRunner.hs
  GHC-Options:        -fhpc -W -Wall -fno-warn-name-shadowing
  CPP-Options:        -DTESTING
```

And I'd like to import some of the modules that `Test/TestRunner.hs` imports. I also want to do this with cabal-dev.

Is there a way to do this without modifying `foo`? If not what would be a good way to patch `foo` to support that?

Maybe a more general version of my question is: *can I tell cabal to give me access to un-exported code in another package?*

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could "tell cabal to give me access to un-exported code in another package". The point of not exporting some modules is to not give users access to it. If cabal just ignored that on a simple switch, it would not respect the authors intentions. If you need access to unexported things, use the source, `cabal unpack`.

Answer (score 2):

As Daniel Fischer suggests, this is probably a stupid thing to ask of cabal. Instead I probably want to fork the lib and export what I need. And maybe git submodules would help here.